# Using created variable in WHERE (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a table of bank transactions in MySQL that appear as so:

| User ID | Date Created | Currency | Amount | USD_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | April 1 | USD | 1000 | 1000 |
| 1 | May 2 | GBP | 100 | 141.90 |
| 2 | April 2 | USD | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | May 5 | EUR | 200 | 243.85 |

The USD_amt is a calculated field from two other tables. I'd like to get the average USD Amount by User ID *as well as* average amount by user ID by month and then filter on the rows where the monthly average is 10 times the user average

Right now, I am trying the following

```
SELECT
    t.user_id,
    t.created_date,
    month(t.created_date),
    year(t.created_date),
    (t.AMOUNT * fx.rate / POWER(10, cd.exponent)) USD_amt,
    avg(t.AMOUNT * fx.rate / POWER(10, cd.exponent)) monthly_avg,
    avg(t.AMOUNT * fx.rate / POWER(10, cd.exponent)) over (partition by t.user_id) user_avg
from
    transactions t
    join fx_rates fx
    on (fx.ccy = t.currency and fx.base_ccy = 'USD')
    join currency_details cd
    on cd.currency = t.currency
where
    monthly_avg > 10* user_avg
group by
    t.user_id,
    t.created_date,
    month(t.created_date),
    year(t.created_date)
```

Although, it doesn't appear I can use the created variable in the WHERE function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use results for the query in the WHERE clause, because WHERE is executed before the results are calculated.

If you want to apply a filter based on the results, you need to use HAVING, which is executed after.

Of course this has performances implications: WHERE allows you to retrieve a subset of results, while HAVING returns all the rows then filters them.

Here's a quick fix on your code that should work

```
SELECT
    t.user_id,
    t.created_date,
    month(t.created_date),
    year(t.created_date),
    (t.AMOUNT * fx.rate / POWER(10, cd.exponent)) USD_amt,
    avg(t.AMOUNT * fx.rate / POWER(10, cd.exponent)) monthly_avg,
    avg(t.AMOUNT * fx.rate / POWER(10, cd.exponent)) over (partition by t.user_id) user_avg
from
    transactions t
    join fx_rates fx
    on (fx.ccy = t.currency and fx.base_ccy = 'USD')
    join currency_details cd
    on cd.currency = t.currency
group by
    t.user_id,
    t.created_date,
    month(t.created_date),
    year(t.created_date)
having
    monthly_avg > 10* user_avg
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrea! I've added the HAVING function, however, now I seem to be getting the following error:                                                                                            
Error Code: 3594. You cannot use the alias 'user_avg' of an expression containing a window function in this context.'